# digital certificates database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relationship

I have a website project which is issue digital certificate instead of paper, so the student can access into his certificates, download it and share it.

I tried to design the datebase and I don't know if I'm doing it right!

here is my schema:
[image]

is the relationships correct ? is there any missing class I should to add ?

also if the relationship between student and certificate as you saw, do I have to add every single certificate to every single student, that will cost a lot of time.

Thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Things seem ok. You need to ensure it meets the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should make another table of enrollment, which will be the link between degree and student, and after that, link the enrollment table with certificates so the certificate will be given to the particular student, who has already enrolled and completed the degree.

For completion you can add an attribute named status in the enrollment table.